# Mocha connects to wrong javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

I am trying to use Mocha for testing some things I'm learning with databases. I have my package.json and other unrelated file in one folder. Inside that folder are two other relevant folders, "test" and "models". Test holds script A which is for establishing a connection with a database, barely related to mocha. And models holds script B which is the Mocha script itself.

Script A:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
});



mongoose.connection.once('open',function(){
    console.log('Connection has been made, now make fireworks...');

}).on('error',function(error){
    console.log('Connection error',error);


});
```

It successfully connects and prints "Connection has been made, now make some fireworks..." like it should.

The mocha file itself, the one I want to run, script B, does this:

```
const mocha = require('mocha');
const assert = require('assert');

//Describe tests
describe('some demo tests', function(){

    // Create tests
    it('adds two numbers together', function(){

        assert(2 + 3 === 5);

    });

});
```

And in my packages.json file I have the following script so I can run it:

```
"test": "mocha",
```

When I run that script, it says:

```
> recreated-site@1.0.0 test C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\recreated site
> mocha



  0 passing (3ms)

Connection has been made, now make fireworks...
```

So it just appears as if it's completely ignoring my mocha script and it just runs the file that connects to the database. Why?

Comment: Hi, I fixed this myself. It turns out that Mocha automatically looks for the folder named "test" and I had my mocha script in the wrong folder.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [asnwer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? It's encouraged so that others can learn from your problem as well.